# Do parabolic/Levi pairs admit dynamic descriptions over disconnected base?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, schemes, reductive-groups

In [Gille](https://hal.science/hal-01063601v2/document), Thm. 7.3.1, it is proven that given a reductive group scheme $G \to S$ over a **connected** base $S$, every parabolic-Levi pair $(P, L)$ over $S$ admits a dynamic description, i.e. is of the form $P = P(\lambda), L = Z(\lambda)$ for an $S$-cocharacter $\lambda : \mathbb{G}_{m,S} \to G_S$.

Doesn't this immediately imply the same result for disconnected base? Writing a general $S$ as $S = \bigsqcup_i S_i$, we can build a cocharacter by specifying it over each connected component, and on each component we can apply the theorem. The construction of $Z(\lambda), P(\lambda)$ is compatible with base change, so this seems to give a dynamic description on all of $S$.

Am I missing something obvious? Is the result thinking only of cocharacters which come from root data, which are required by definition to be uniform over the base? Is there an implicit assumption of this uniformity whenever we talk about characters/cocharacters for a relative reductive group scheme?